# Formatting Sections, Subsesctions and SubSubsections for Legal Contracts

Tags: formatting, legal-style

LaTeX looks like it might potentially be a powerful tool for writing legal contracts.

My contracts are formatted quite simply with three descending heading levels.  Each heading level is progressively indented .62 cm.  The number format progression is as follows: 1. - (a) - (i).

There is also basic text - some of which is centred, others indented and others hanging below a heading.

I am using `\documentclass{report}` and I have not seen any straightforward way to set formatting.  Am I missing something?

Simple contract:

> ```
> 1. Section (also boldface, all capitals and underlined)
>
>    (b) Subsection - with possibly some text added.
>
>        (i) Subsubsection - also possibly with some text.
> ```

Comment: Can you include an illustration? Seems you are asking a good question, I just can't quite imagine that.

Comment: I added an illustration to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a package called `\titlesec` It's a really nice package that lets you change your `section subsection` and `subsubsection`. You use it like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\huge\bfseries\uppercase}      % What the formating looks like of the entire section
{\thesection}         % This is for numbering, you can also leave it blank, or put simething else.
{0em}                 % This argument is for the distance, the distance between the       second argument and that we feed to \titleformat
{}[\titlerule]                    % After the gap, between the number and the title but before the title
\begin{document}
\section{Some Section}
This is an example section.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GeorgeousMagnificus Since you are new around here, I thought it would be a good idea to remind you to accept the answer which works for you. That way, future/current users who are looking for similar answers might find it useful too.

Comment: Thanks - I haven't tried it yet so I can't confirm that it worked.

Comment: If you dont need chapters (with bold large headings and starting on a new page) dont use `report` class but prefer `article`, where the `\section'`s feature continuous text.